# React, MUI - Why does Keyboard component not come out on Input field click?

Tags: reactjs, material-ui

I have the following case: when clicking on the Input component inside the Drawer, the virtual keyboard should open. However, if I render a block that depends on the keyboard visibility state, nothing happens.

```
{ isKeyboardVisible && <Box height="260px" width="100%" /> }
```

I don't understand why the keyboard is not opening when clicking on the input field and how to fix this bug.

You can find an example of the bug in this repository: https://github.com/malmo-east/material-drawer-keyboard-bug.

Thanks for any help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change your **onFocus** in your input component to **onClick**;

```
    <Input
      placeholder={"test"}
      value={inputVal}
      disableUnderline
      autoFocus={false}
      fullWidth
      onClick={() => setKeyboardVisible(true)}
    />
```

This happens because your focus event triggers before your click event. And before the click event triggers it just sends an empty element and it triggers an event on body.

This code below is what makes the keyboard disappear. It is in index.tsx file and when you trigger an event on anything other than the element matches one of these statements it just makes the keyboard disappear.

```
function clickHandler(e: any) {
  if (
    !e.target.classList.contains('MuiInput-root') &&
    !(e.target.nodeName === 'INPUT') &&
    !e.target.classList.contains('hg-button') &&
    !e.target.classList.contains('hg-row') &&
    !e.target.classList.contains('keyboard-wrapper')
  ) {
    if (onHide) {
      onHide(false);
    }
    setKeyboardVisible(false);
  }
}
```

Keep in mind that if you want to use **onFocus** you can change the **click** listener that triggers **clickHandler()** function to **mousedown** listener.

[live demo](https://codesandbox.io/s/frosty-sun-oschst?file=/src/App.tsx)